# let declarations being hoisted to top of their scope

Tags: javascript

If I write this then it prints undefined:

```
let a  
console.log(a)
a = 20
```

but why does this return an error, then?

```
console.log(a)
let a = 20
```

`a` gets hoisted to the top in case 2 and since JavaScript doesn’t assign any value to let in memory allocation phase it returns error. But isn’t the condition similar in case 1 also? Then why does it print undefined in case 1?

Answer (score 2):

- `let a` is exactly like `let a = undefined`
- It’s intentionally an error to access a variable declared with `let` (or `const` or `class`) before the declaration. That’s just how it works, because it makes the most sense that way.

Definitely don’t think about it in terms of a “memory allocation phase”.

Comment: so why is there an error in case 2?

Comment: since they are in temporal dead zone , they should throw an error in case 1 also . am i right?

Comment: @lakshya: No, the temporal dead zone ends at `let a` even if you don’t specify `= undefined` explicitly. Case 1 is fine.